# Como acessar os atributos (ou annotations) do PHP 8?

Tags: php, php-8

Estou experimentando com os atributos (ou *annotations*) do PHP 8. Criei algumas classes de exemplo e adicionei os atributos de classe, propriedade e método.

```php
<?php

#[Attribute]
class ClassAttribute {}

#[Attribute]
class PropertyAttribute {}

#[Attribute]
class MethodAttribute {}

#[ClassAttribute]
class Sample {
    #[PropertyAttribute]
    protected $myAttribute;

    #[MethodAttribute]
    public function myFunction() {}
}
```

Como acessar esses atributos com `Reflection`? Na documentação das classes de [`Reflection`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) não existem os métodos de atributos dos [exemplos dos atributos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.attributes.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É possível acessar atributos de classe, propriedade e métodos através do método `getAttributes()` (ainda não documentado) respectivamente das classes `ReflectionClass`, `ReflectionProperty` e `ReflectionMethod`:

```php
$classReflection = new ReflectionClass(Sample::class);
$classAttributes = $classReflection->getAttributes();

$methodReflection = new ReflectionMethod(Sample::class, 'myFunction');
$methodAttributes = $methodReflection->getAttributes();

$propertyReflection = new ReflectionProperty(Sample::class, 'myAttribute');
$propertyAttributes = $propertyReflection->getAttributes();
```

Para a classe é possível usar também o `ReflectionObject`.

Assim `$classAttributes`, `$methodAttributes` e `$propertyAttributes` são *arrays* de instâncias de `ReflectionAttribute` (ainda não documentada também), a partir delas é possível chamar os métodos dos exemplos na documentação:

```php
$classAttributes[0]->getName();
$classAttributes[0]->getArguments();
$classAttributes[0]->newInstance();
```

Ao executar `var_dump` nesses métodos é exibido o seguinte:

```
string(14) "ClassAttribute"
array(0) {
}
object(ClassAttribute)#7 (0) {
}
```

Esse jeito funciona quando o nome das propriedades ou dos métodos é conhecido. Quando o nome é desconhecido é preciso iterar a instância de `ReflectionObject` ou `ReflectionClass` com [`getProperties`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getproperties.php) ou  [`getMethods`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getmethods.php). Essas funções retornam *arrays* contendo instâncias de `ReflectionProperty` e `ReflectionMethod`, das quais os atributos poder ser obtidos conforme o exemplo anterior.

```php
$classReflection = new ReflectionClass(Sample::class);
$classMethods = $classReflection->getMethods();
foreach ($classMethods as $methodReflection) {
  $methodReflection->getAttributes();
}
$classMethods = $classReflection->getProperties();
foreach ($classProperties as $propertyReflection) {
  $propertyReflection->getAttributes();
}
```